# magento 1.9 Newly added products are not showing in category page?

Tags: magento, product

Product enabled : Yes

Visibility : Catalog, search

Product Images : All good

Quantity Available : 9999999

Stock Availability : In Stock

Assign to a category : Yes (I even went to Manage Category to see product is under Category products and its there)

Product in web sites : Assigned

Cache : Cleared 10 X times

Indexing : Done

Magento Newly added Products are not showing in category page?i am checking all the above points are correct but products are not showing in category page?

Plz give me the solution

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

Check 3 more things:

- **Catalog->Manage products->Product information->Websites**: see if the desired website is checked. This option appears only if you have a multishop configured, thsu more than 1 website.
- **Catalog->Manage categories->[your category]->Display settings->Display mode**: set it to 'Products only' or 'Statis block and products'
- **Catalog->Manage categories->[your category]->Display settings->Is anchor**: set it to 'Yes'